# Using Recursion in Python to Write Elements and Their Types to a Text File

Tags: python, recursion

I'm very new to Python so please bear with me. I'm currently trying to create a function using recursion that will iterate through a list and for each item that's an integer will write to a text file I (for integer) + the value. This is what I have so far: 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def save(file, value):
    output = ''
    if len(value) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        element = value[0]
        if type(element) == int:
            output += 'I' + element
            save(f, element+1)
        else:
            pass
    print(output)

a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 1, 2, 3, 4]


with open('forlater.txt', mode='w') as f:
    save(f, a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple issues with the way you pass arguments in the recursive call. The first issue is that in the recursive call you pass an integer as `value`, but `value` is meant to be a list (better naming would help with this). The second is that `output` is not passed down in the recursive call nor is it returned.

Another issue is that `save` is not called again if the type of `element` is not `int`, so currently `save` will only be called once since the first element of `a` is a string.

With these in mind, here is a refactor of your code:

```
def save(file, values, output=''):
    if len(values) == 0:
        f.write(output)
    else:
        element = values[0]
        if type(element) == int:
            output += 'I' + str(element)

        #outside `if` block
        remaining_values = values[1:]
        save(f, remaining_values, output=output)


a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 1, 2, 3, 4]

with open('forlater.txt', mode='w') as f:
    save(f, a)
```

Which, writes the following to the file:

```
I1I2I3I4
```

You may want to include some spacing or new lines.

Also consider that this problem does not really need to use recursion, a `for` loop would be a simpler way to accomplish the job:

```
def save(file, values):
    output = ''
    for element in values:
        if type(element) == int:
            output += 'I' + str(element)

    f.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion to do this, you just need to iterate through the list and for each element write what you want. Replace your first  `if else` block of your function with this:

```
for element in value:
    if type(element) == int:
        output = 'I' + str(element)
        f.write(output)
```

You can also use list comprehension

```
[f.write('I' + str(element) for element in value if type(element) == int]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion:

```
def my_homework(list, file):
    if len(list) > 1:
        my_homework(list[1:], file)
    if isinstance(list[0], int):
        print("I" + str(list[0]), file=file)
```

This isn't going to keep the order you've got though.